# Script is not working on resize in actual device

Tags: jquery, mobile, response

Here I want to set `margin-left` for a particular article through JavaScript if it is a single article on load and resize events. Both are working fine in the mobile view of browsers. But on actual devices, `onload` is working fine but `onresize` , `margin-left` is not getting set as intended

**Code in Context**

```
<script>
  function setWidth()
  {
    var width=$('.featured-block .article').width(); var   margin=width+15;
    if($('.featured-block .article').size()==1 && $(window).width()<500) {
      $('.featured-block .article').css('margin-left',margin);

      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.featured-block .article').css('width',width);
      }, 100);
    }
    else{
       $('.featured-block .article').css('margin-left',0);
      }
  }
  $(window).load(function(){
    var widthOnLoad=$(window).width();
    alert('load');
    setWidth();
    $(window).resize(function(){
      var widthOnResize=$(window).width();
      if(widthOnResize != widthOnLoad)
      {
        setWidth(); 
        widthOnLoad=$(window).width();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

On changing from portrait to landscape and then again to portrait, margin is not getting set.

Comment: Put window resize function outside of the window load function

Comment: Thanks SESN, But if I do so, I cant make use of "widthOnLoad" variable as it is there in load fuction. As a result resize event fires on scroll also.

Comment: Try to put ur code in fiddle?